# When should I use a comma with 'but'?

Tags: punctuation

Here are two sentences

> It’s an old car, but it’s very reliable.
>
> I’d like to go but I’m too busy.

*(from [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/but))*

I see no difference(,) but one of them has a comma, the other doesn't. Why? What are the rules?

Comment: See the answer to this question at: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28277/using-a-comma-before-but

Comment: I'm surprised that the above discussion starts with the assumption that commas are always wrong before "but". I always use a comma before *but* unless it's clearly wrong, as in one of the examples in the OP's link: "an expensive but extremely useful book", and this seems to match StephenS's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It’s an old car, but it’s very reliable.
>
> I’d like to go but I’m too busy.

The second is incorrect; it should have a comma.

The rule is that if you’re joining two independent clauses, you use a comma:

> It’s an old car. It’s very reliable.
>
> It’s an old car, but it’s very reliable.
>
> I’d like to go. I’m too busy.
>
> I’d like to go, but I’m too busy.

If you’re joining things that are not independent clauses, you don’t:

> It’s an old car but very reliable.
>
> I would like to go but am too busy.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but you're last example does not sound not quite right to me. It is probably fine in conversational English, but (no pun intended) for the standard written English, I suppose the comma is needed. I am not a Native speaker of English though, just saying what I think.

Comment: @Cardinal It’s grammatical; you can’t use a comma because the clauses share a subject, though they don’t share a verb like in the previous example.

Comment: @JamesK The statement *"The second is **incorrect**; it **should** have a comma."* is incorrect, and so is *"The **rule** is that if you’re joining two independent clauses, you use a comma"*. In this case, there is no "rule" that says one must **always** use a comma when joining two independent cases. Yes, when two independent clauses are connected with a conjunction, a comma is often used. In this case, one could choose to use the comma or omit it. Omitting it does not make it incorrect.

Comment: @JamesK Chicago, MLA, APA recognize that if independent clauses are short, the comma may be omitted. - hence the "rule" stated above is not really a strict "rule". Chicago says *"When independent clauses are joined by **and, but, or, so, yet**, or any other coordinating conjunction, a comma usually precedes the conjunction. If the clauses are very short and closely connected, the comma **may** be omitted."* (Source: CMoS 17th ed., 6.22) Of course, we should *not* omit the comma if there is any chance of ambiguity, even if clauses are short. There is no ambiguity here.

Comment: @AIQ I consciously break many rules as a matter of personal style; IMHO, style does not invalidate the rule being broken.